# Add icon near hamburger to navigation drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

Actually I have this hamburger icon in my navigation drawer auto generated by eclipse:

[image]

I would get this result:

[image]

Comment: I think this one will help you [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38373481/remove-large-padding-after-hamburger-menu-icon-in-android-toolbar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing, always show what you have tried resolve your query.

Second to answer this, try

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setLogo(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

place this in your widget

```
android:drawableRight="@drawable/image"
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please quote the most relevant part of the link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. See [How do I write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).